# Azure Function HTTP request body mapping does not work when published

Tags: c#, azure, azure-functions

I have an Azure Function, with this declaration:

```
 public static async Task<IActionResult> Run([HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "get", Route = "GetServicesByEanCode/")]GetServicesByEanCode_Request httpReq, ILogger log)
```

The request object is defined as

```
   [DataContract]
    public class GetServicesByEanCode_Request
    {
        [DataMember(IsRequired = true)]
        public string EanCode { get; set; }
    }
```

If I run my function locally, a HTTP request with the following body will work perfect, and httpReq is being populated with the value of "eancode":

```
{ "eancode":"123"}
```

However, after I publish the function to an Azure Function, the request object is not being populated at all, using the same request body.

If I set "eancode" as a parameter in my request it works for both (local and published). But I can't figure out why it only map in one of the two situations. What can I possibly be missing here?

Answer (score 0):

I reproduce your problem.

After deploy to azure, I get 404 error when using request body.Then I select Http Method as `Get` (though you have set get method in local but after deploy it is null so you need to select it)and test again, it works fine now.

[image]

Comment: I don't get a 404, just an unpopulated property :/ Enabled remote debugging, and the same request to local vs published function get different results. If I enter any value in the request body, e.g. { "eancode":"foo bar" }, the response from my local instance is "No service found with EAN code 'foo bar'", while the published version responds with "No service found with EAN code ' ' ". I've verified this by using remote debugging and breakpoints.